# How does the scipy.stats.shapiro calculate a test statistic

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, scipy.stats

I know that [scipy.stats.shapiro](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.shapiro.html) is used to test for normality. I also know that the calculation of a test statistic always involves the mean m<sub>0</sub> or variance of the population (as explained [here](https://www.statlect.com/glossary/test-statistic)). My question then:

1. What type of test statistic (t, chi-square or something else) does the `shapiro()` calculate?
2. What is the value of mean or variance of the population does it use to calculate the test statistic?

Could someone please explain and give a concrete example showing how the function obtain the mean or variance of the population?

Answer (score 0):

> What type of test statistic (t, chi-square or something else) does the shapiro() calculate?

Something else. `scipy.stats.shapiro` uses the [Shapiro-Wilk statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test). The calculation is a quite a bit more involved than other common statistics. To understand it, you'll need to learn more about both sample and random variable [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) and understand the idea of the expected value of order statistics and covariance between order statistics.

> What is the value of mean or variance of the population does it use to calculate the test statistic?

The test statistic does not involve the value of the population mean or variance. The test statistic does, however, involve the sample mean.

> Could someone please explain and give a concrete example showing how the function obtain the mean or variance of the population?

The function does not obtain the mean or variance of the population. It uses the sample mean of the provided sample. Here is a concrete example of computing a sample mean given a sample.

```py
import numpy as np
samples = [1, 2, 3]  # a sample
np.mean(sample)  # the sample mean
```

Other test statistics, such as the statistic used in the one-sample t-test, may involve the *hypothesized* sample mean (not the true sample mean). Others may involve a population statistic. For instance, z-tests assume that the population standard deviation is known. In both cases the user would provide these separately from the sample(s); they cannot be determined from the sample(s).